# What explains the relationship between the words "flower" and "world"?

Tags: etymology

In Serbian the words "svet" (world) and "cvet" (flower) are very similar.

In Hungarian the words are "vilag" (world) and "virag" (flower).

I found this an interesting curiosity.

Any etymological reasons for this similarity, or other languages where these words are also similar?

Answer (score 1):

The Serbian words are from the same root, with the original sense of the PIE root being "to shine". The idea of the world we live in as a bright world opposed to a dark underworld appears in several Indo-European branches (notably Celtic, but also Romanian, possibly as a result of Slavic influence and flowers' bright colours make them naturally associated with shining.

The Hungarian words are actually világ & virág (note the acute accents marking the long a). Wiktionary says the two are a doublet from the same root, but this is unsourced, and as far as I know, the l/r alternation would be unusual within Hungarian, so I think it's worth taking that claim with a little pinch of salt. That said, világ is cognate with Finnish valkea & Northern Sami vielgat, both meaning "white", so the semantic connection (assuming the words are connected) appears to be the same.

In both cases the semantic development seems to be, on the one hand light > upperworld (as opposed to the underworld) > world, and on the other hand light > bright > flower.

Neither semantic development is especially unusual, but the former is definitely less common. This parallel is common throughout almost all of Slavic (although the parallel is much weaker in East Slavic, especially Russian & Belarusian, which use a diminutive form of the word for flower). Other than Hungarian and , I'm not sure of any specific other language that has undergone both developments from the same root (as opposed to both developments from synonymous roots) though, and the parallel is absent in the Baltic languages - Slavic's closest relatives.

Comment: Which Celtic word are you thinking of here? Of the two Celtic words for ‘world’ that I can think of off the top of my head, [_*bitus_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Celtic/bitus) is from PIE _*gʷei̯h₃-_ and thus means ‘life > world’, while [_*dubnos_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Celtic/dubnos) is from _*dʰeu̯bʰ-_ ‘deep, dark’ and would thus – if anything – relate to the _underworld_, rather than the upperworld.

Comment: Worth to note that they use a different first consonant in West Slavic and Baltic květ/svět and the k for the flower is also reconstructed for Proto-Slavic and the c or s appeared after the second palatelization. but they are doublets originally indeed from the same PIE root which begs for the question, why there was the divergence in the first place.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was thinking of Alba "Scotland" & the Alps < *albiyū, one of the meanings of which is usually given as "upperworld"

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава good point on the initial k rather than c in flower in West Slavic, the phonetic parallel isn't quite as good there. The flower word appears to have undergone irregular centumisation, hence the initial *k in Proto-Slavic (preserved in West Slavic, palatalised to c elsewhere)